# Pandas dataframe removes certain rows after downloading as csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2gb csv file, which was created using pandas. This is what the dataframe looked like before downloading it as a .csv file:

```
id, x, y
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
2, 1, 2
```

x and y was created using the merge function (I merged it on the id column).
This is what it looks like after I download it as a csv (using the to_csv function) and parse it into a df (using the read_csv function):

```
id, x, y
1, NaN, NaN
1, 2, 3
2, 1, 2
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: `df.groupby('id').bfill()` ? not sure why it would remvoe your data after downloading perhaps your csv is corrupt?

Comment: How looks code of merge function with your data? One reason should be mix `1` like `string` - `'1'` and numbers, `1` - so if used left join `'1'` should not merged (I only guess, it is data related problem)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it helps you but how are you creating this .csv file? Are you using a dictionary? Here is my example of how can look writing function and I've already checked it and python is reading it well, without NaNs.

```
fieldnames = ['id','x','y']
rows = [
        {'id': 1,
        'x': 2,
        'y': 3},
        {'id': 1,
         'x': 2,
         'y': 3},
        {'id': 2,
         'x': 1,
         'y': 2},]

with open('example.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: But you have some error or it does not match with your idea of the answer?

Comment: It just does not match with the idea